# Como validar la hora que seleccionó el usuario sea de formato 24 horas Php,Js,JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html5, jquery-ui

Buenos días tengo este campo de tipo time en html lo que debo de hacer es validar que la hora que seleccionó el usuario sea en formato 24 horas, debido a que algunos computadores de los usuarios estan en ingles, no he podido encontrar como validar esa hora alguien me puede hacer el favor de ayudarme?

```
<input type="time" name="HoraEntradaEstablecida" id="HoraEntradaEstablecida" >
```

Comment: ¿y que les ocurre a los usuarios que están en inglés?  ¿no ven ese campo como nosotros?  ¿sus dias no son de 24 horas?  ¿o les sale lo del am/pm en ese tipo de campo?

Comment: Vale, creo que no debes preocuparte, pues ese campo varia segun la hora local y el navegador que usen, pero tal como se indica en [su documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time), `The value of the time input is always in 24-hour format` hagan lo que hagan, por lo tanto tu vas a recibir los datos correctamente aunque a ellos se les muestre con todas esas variantes.